# Sequelize ORM: Using Deferrable constraints on junction table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use a Many:Many association with Sequelize (against a Postgre db).

I want to create a *venue* and associate it with a *user* in a single transaction. The venues and users are set up as normal Sequelize models, and are each set to "belongToMany" of the other through junction table "userVenue".

The issue is I can't seem to create a new *venue* and also its first *user* association in the same transaction. Postgre throws the following error:

```
insert or update on table "userVenues" violates foreign key constraint "userVenues_venueId_fkey"
```

since the new *venue* hasn't been committed yet.

I think I need to set the foreign key constraints on "userId" and "venueId" in the "userVenues" junction table to be initially deferrable as per [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/variable/index.html#static-variable-Deferrable), however, as Sequelize is defining the junction table's "userId" and "venueId" automatically, I can't figure out how to set them to be INITIALLY_DEFERRABLE.

I have tried simply setting the transaction to SET_DEFERRED (as per the same doc), and I can see in the logs that it does issue the command "SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED" to the DB, however since Sequelize seems to default the constraints to NOT (deferrable) I still fail with the same error. If I don't use a transaction the two sequential INSERTS work just fine.

Is there a way to define these foreign keys as deferrable? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Many thanks!

Relevant code below:

```html
  // *** ASSOCIATIONS ***
  
  // The Venue association
  Venue.belongsToMany(models.user, {
    through: models.userVenue,
  });
  
    // The User association
  User.belongsToMany(models.venue, {
    through: models.userVenue,
  });
  
  
  
  // *** THE TRANSACTION ***
  const newVenue = await db.sequelize.transaction(
  { deferrable: Sequelize.Deferrable.SET_DEFERRED },
  async (t) => {
    const newRow = await db.venue.create(
      { ...payload },
      { transaction: t }
    );

    await newRow.addUser(
      socket.user,
      {
        through: { permit: 'edit' },
      },
      { transaction: t }
    );

    return newRow;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure this `{
        through: { permit: 'edit' },
      },
      { transaction: t }`
Should not be `{
        through: { permit: 'edit' },
        transaction: t }`?

Comment: Hey, you're absolutely right! Thanks for pointing that out. I realized this yesterday but forgot to update this post. The transaction was not specified correctly, but I didn't realize because when this line failed the whole transaction rolled back, so I assumed it was correctly included in the transaction. However I forgot that throwing any error in the middle of the managed transaction will abort the whole thing... oops!

I didn't think I should need a deferrable constraint in this simple transaction, and turns out I didn't... just better attention to syntax!

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it seems like this might be a bug in Sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8194

Though it has been flagged as a bug there has been no fix yet. One helpful user replied to my post in that thread with a potential fix, but at the moment there is no pull request.

The workaround I am currently using, should anyone find it helpful, is the run this raw query after the DB Sync to alter the constraint. It does require knowledge of the constraint name.

```html
    await sequelize.query(
      'ALTER TABLE "userVenues" ALTER CONSTRAINT "userVenues_venueId_fkey" DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED'
    );
```